# Объединение ячеек по условию с помощью pandas python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Помогите пожалуйста в решении проблемы.
Существует таблица примерно такого вида:

| clmn1 | clmn2 | clmn3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | ooooo | 11 |
| 11111 | ppppp | 11 |
| 22222 | nnnnn | 22 |
| 33333 | hhhhh | 33 |
| 33333 | jjjjj | 33 |
| 33333 | bbbbb | 33 |

Должно получиться:

| clmn1 | clmn2 | clmn3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | oooooppppp | 11 |
| 22222 | nnnnn | 22 |
| 33333 | hhhhhjjjjjbbbbb | 33 |

Программа должна по уникальным id из первого столбца сложить текст из второго столбца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = df.groupby("clmn1").agg({"clmn2":"sum","clmn3":"first"}).reset_index()
```

res:

```
   clmn1            clmn2  clmn3
0  11111       oooooppppp     11
1  22222            nnnnn     22
2  33333  hhhhhjjjjjbbbbb     33
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

s = '''
11111   ooooo
11111   ppppp
22222   nnnnn
33333   hhhhh
33333   jjjjj
33333   bbbbb'''

df = pd.DataFrame({'clmn1': s.split()[::2], 'clmn2': s.split()[1::2]})

df1 = df.groupby('clmn1').sum().reset_index()
```

Содержимое `df1`:

```
    clmn1   clmn2
0   11111   oooooppppp
1   22222   nnnnn
2   33333   hhhhhjjjjjbbbbb
```

Про третий столбец только теперь увидел, но, кажется, его можно добавить в группировку, либо присоединить потом через `merge`, и ничего особо не поменяется.